# Use result from one query as an input into another query on MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to use a result from one query as input for another query but I am stumped.  I thought about using JOIN but I think in this case the two queries need to me run separately.  Essentially I have a list of articles in my database.  As I loop through the list or articles that I obtained from my first query I want to search a second table to find out the number of votes that each article has.

This is the code:

```
<?php
  $sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM discussion_links WHERE link_side = 'Michigan'");
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
?>

<div class="top-links-wrapper">
    <div>
       <div class="link-info">
           <a class="link-title" href="http://<?php echo $row['link_url'] ?>">
           <?php echo $row['link_title'] . "</a>"; ?>
           <p class="link-source"><?php echo $row['link_source'] . "</p>" ?>
       </div>
       <div class="link-vote-wrapper">
           <span class="link-votes">
           <?php    
                $sql2=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM link_votes WHERE link_id = " . $row['link_id'] .")";
                $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($sql2);
                echo "$num_rows";
            ?>
           </span>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [**red box**](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: Thanks @Truth, new to this so better learn the new standards.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can join both queries try this

```
SELECT dl.* , lv.*
FROM discussion_links dl
LEFT JOIN link_votes lv ON lv.link_id = dl.link_id
WHERE link_side = 'Michigan'
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
$sql2=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM link_votes WHERE link_id = " . $row['link_id'] .")";
```

to

```
$sql2=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM link_votes WHERE link_id = " . $row['link_id']);
```

The closing bracket `)` is part of the function call not the query

or better would be to create a single query :

```
SELECT * FROM discussion_links d 
JOIN link_votes v
on d.link_id = v.link_id
WHERE d.link_side = 'Michigan'
```

You should replace the `SELECT *` and just select the columns you require

Comment: Thanks, just noticed the error with the ')'.  Will try that 2nd query you suggest.

Comment: @LuisP you may need to do a `left join` as there may be articles that have no votes

Answer (score 0):

Fixed, had an error in the 2nd query:

```
$sql2=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM link_votes WHERE link_id = " . $row['link_id']);
```

It now works.